# Does function overloading work in C?

Tags: c, overloading

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [function overloading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c)
>   [Does C support overloading ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)

Can anyone explain if function overloading work in C?

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int val) {
    printf("f int\n");
    return 5;
}

int f(char *val) {
    printf("f char *\n");
    return 6;
}

int main() {
    f(5);
    f("moo");
}
```

The gcc C compiler says:

```
overload.c:8: error: conflicting types for 'f'
overload.c:3: error: previous definition of 'f' was here
```

However, if I compile the same code in C++, it works.

Can anyone explain it?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: No, C does not support overloaded functions. The two languages are very different.

Comment: More a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, C has no function overloading.

Answer (score 3):

Function overloading is one of the additional features of C++ that are often described as "C++ as a better C".

It has nothing to do with the object-oriented features of C++.