# Function prototype with ellipsis

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I was wondering if the below function prototype is valid. It compiled fine, but the three period is kinda throwing me off and I couldn't find anything similar on Google.

```
void foo(int, ...);
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317811/how-to-use-variable-argument

Comment: To google it don't forget to provide `...` like this in search criteria: `"..."`

Comment: By the way, the C++ standard says "ellipsis" rather than "ellipse" or "ellipses" which may be contrary to your google efforts.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the tips guys. And sorry for making a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. In this example, `...` creates a variadic function using the `va_list` mechanism. This is how variadic functions are implemented in C, and to some degree in C++ (though C++11's template parameter packs have rendered this mechanism obsolete).

Further reading: [va_arg](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg)