# Does printf support function overloading In C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does C support overloading ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)

I would like to know if printf supports function overloading in C, since same printf function may be used in more than one way in one C program.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  Please give a code example of what you would like to be able to do.

Comment: printf uses a variable argument list.  It's not the same as function overloading.

Comment: It is a read question albeit a very poorly worded one.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the difference between

```
printf("something: %d\n", number);
printf("something else: %d, %s\n", number, string);
```

this has nothing to do with overloading. It's just a
[variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Answer (score 3):

`printf()` in C is a variadic function which can be thought of as a form of overloading. Unlike overloaded functions in languages like C++, Java, C# etc., a variadic function is not type-safe which is why they are somewhat frowned upon.

Comment: I _nearly_ want to downvote, variadic-functions and function-overloading are very different things (there is only one printf function, not different implementations depending on parameters). You're skating close to the edge with your "can be thought of as" :)

Comment: @Binary All sorts of things can be thought of as overloading in its most general form. If you want to take overloading as being strictly meaning C++ overloaded functions, then no its different. But just as polymorpism can mean many things, so can overloading.

Comment: Agreed, however I can think of a cats and dogs as "Animals" in their most general form, but It won't help my Irish Wolfhound catch mice :) Just saying I think _this case is more specific than general_ . . . and unfortunately no, I don't own an Irish Wolfhound.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how `printf` takes different numbers and types of arguements, then no, it isn't function overloading. Functions can be defined to take variable argument lists.

Look at [stdarg.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) for working with variable arguement lists

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have signature based polymorphism so you can't do this. There are a few ways you can sort of do this listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c/479212#479212).

The more important question is why you would want to do this? Why is printf not generic enough for you?