# Method overloading in C with printf?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the signature of printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633367/what-is-the-signature-of-printf)
>   [Does C support overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)
>   [Does printf support function overloading In C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802382/does-printf-support-function-overloading-in-c)

C's `printf` function seems to show method overloading as different types of arguments can be given to it. Is this right or `printf` is something else?

Comment: printf uses the ellipsis operator (...) - http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/c-ellipsis-operator-printf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`printf()`is something else that is called [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). The exact number and types of its arguments is specified through its first one, the format.

Other variadic functions have other ways of specifying number and/or type of arguments but it is always through one fixed argument.

Comment: @Shashank Jain, you should accept an answer if you think it answers your question, it's different from just upvoting.

Comment: i was waiting for 8 minutes to pass. stackoverflow wasn't allowing to vote before that

Answer (score 5):

It's not method overloading at all. Method overloading respects types. `printf` just flat out ignores them and hopes you got it right in the format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D), so it determines at *run-time* how many arguments to expect based on the format specifier you give it.

Whether that counts as "overloading" depends on your definition!  Most people would say it isn't, because it's nothing to do with the compiler (only one function is instantiated in binary).  But from the user's perspective, it still acts a lot like overloading (just not type-safe).

Comment: type safety is extremely important. Acting like overloading but not type safe would be like having sex but not having fun.

Comment: How can it be overloading when there is only one printf?

Comment: @Nicola: Why does the underlying implementation matter?  As far as the user is concerned, variadic functions can have some of the characteristics of "true" overloaded functions (the [`open()` sys-call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) is a good example of this).

Comment: Depends on your definition of overloading ;-)

Comment: @Oli: overloading means to use the same name for more than one thing; it is commonly used to indicate the possibility of defining functions with the same name, provided their argument types and/or number is different. C doesn't support overloading and the standard C library is defined so that it may be implemented in C itself. Variadic functions with unconstrained argument types are a different way to achieve a similar effect. In the context of implementation techniques, which in my opinion is underlying the OP's question, confusing the two concepts is misleading.