# Error in c program with two function having same return types and names but different function signature

Tags: c

Is this allowed in c?

```
void hello(int a, float y)
{


    int s = a + y;
    printf("value in hello = %d \n",s);

}

void hello(int a, int b, int c)
{


    int s = a + b + c;
    printf("value in hello 2 = %d \n", s);

}


int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    hello(2, 3.5);
    hello(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Aren't the functions signatures different here?

I am getting an error :

```
prog.c:11:6: error: conflicting types for 'hello'
 void hello(int a,int b,int c)
      ^
prog.c:2:6: note: previous definition of 'hello' was here
 void hello(int a,float y)
      ^
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:24:2: error: too few arguments to function 'hello'
  hello(2,3.5);
  ^
prog.c:11:6: note: declared here
 void hello(int a,int b,int c)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not allowed. C doesn't allow function overloading.

The closest you can get is to write a [*variadic functions*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

For example, the Unix [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) system call *pretends* to support two different interfaces:

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

But in fact, it's a variadic function.

Comment: It would be easier to have a default value for `mode` in `open`.

Comment: @mch There's also `creat(2)` which provides default *flags*. I just used`open(2)` as an example that the interface is given with two distinct signatures but actually implemented as a variadic function.

Comment: @mch *It would be easier to have a default value for mode in `open`.*  And that would break every bit of preexisting code.  C is not C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature called *function overloading*. It is not allowed in C language.

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed.

C isn't like modern OOP (C# or Java) where methods with the same name but different signatures are allowed.

This feature is called `function overloading` and not available in C.

You can read this

[Does C support overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)

for more details.

Comment: Overloading and OOP have nothng to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

As several other posters has already said, this is not supported in plain C. However there are some tricks you can use. If you are using C11, you can use `_Generic` macros. This is usable when the called function should have different behavior based on the type of the arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello_f( float f ){ printf("I'm a float: %f\n", f ); }
void hello_i( int i ){ printf("I'm an integer: %d\n", i ); }
#define hello(x) _Generic((x), int: hello_i, float: hello_f)(x)
int main(){
    hello( 2 );
    hello( 2.0f );
    return 0;
}
```

Works like this:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 generic_test.c && a.exe
I'm an integer: 2
I'm a float: 2.000000
```

There is also an other trick to mimic the behavior of overloading if the signature differs in the number of arguments. This trick is usable in C99 as it uses variadic macros.

```
/* Your original functions renamed */
void hello_int_float(int a,float y){
    int s = a + y;
    printf("value in hello = %d \n",s);
}

void hello_int_int_int(int a,int b,int c){
    int s = a + b + c;
    printf("value in hello 2 = %d \n",s);
}

#define VA_WHAT_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define VA_WHAT(...) VA_WHAT_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, int_int_int, int_float, one_arg)

#define hello_impl2(signature_count, ...) hello_ ## signature_count (__VA_ARGS__)
#define hello_impl(what, ...) hello_impl2(what, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define hello(...) hello_impl(VA_WHAT(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

int main(){
    hello( 2, 1.0f);
    hello( 1, 3, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this method is not really safe in the sense that you get a useful error message if the number of arguments is not supported or the argument type is not correct. **It only counts the number of arguments.** Here is what the code expands to:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -E overload.c
# 1 "overload.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "overload.c"

void hello_int_float(int a,float y){
    int s = a + y;
    printf("value in hello = %d \n",s);
}
void hello_int_int_int(int a,int b,int c){
    int s = a + b + c;
    printf("value in hello 2 = %d \n",s);
}
# 19 "overload.c"
int main(){
    hello_int_float (2, 1.0f);
    hello_int_int_int (1, 3, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I have actually used this trick in real code.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support overloading, as others have said. I'll try to show you why.

If you compile:

```
// file1.c
int helloi(int a) { 
    return a; 
}

int hellofff(float a, float b, float c) {
    return a * b * c;
}
```

with `gcc -c file1.c`

and you can check the output file's symbols:

```
$ nm file1.o 
000000000000000c T hellofff
0000000000000000 T helloi
```

The functions name's are exactly the same as they are in the code. This is because C preserves function and global variable names for linking.

Let's use overloading to do the same thing in C++

```
// file2.cpp
int hello(int a) {
    return a;
}

int hello(float a, float b, float c) {
    return a * b * c;
}
```

compile it and check it's symbols:

```
$ g++ -c file2.cpp 
$ nm file2.o 
000000000000000c T _Z5hellofff
0000000000000000 T _Z5helloi
```

It's done what we did manually in C. It's also inserted a `_Z5` at the front. The `_Z` says "this is a GCC mangled name". The `5` means the actual name is 5 bytes long, after that is the types. (Otherwise you wouldn't you tell the difference between helloi() and hello(int).)

We can even call these "Mangled" (technical term) names from C:

```
// file3.c
#include <stdio.h>

int _Z5hellofff(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void) {
    printf("hello(1, 2, 3) == %d\n", _Z5hellofff(1, 2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

And compile with: `gcc -o file3 file3.c file2.o`

And hopefully it links and runs. There a few other formats, such as the ones used by Microsoft, Go, Rust and more. (Rust also uses `_ZNname` but after that it becomes hard to decipher gibberish)

The reason for it starting with a `_Z` is that in C, identifies starting with `_Z` are reserved by the compiler/libc, and users shouldn't use them for their own things (it's okay here, because we know what the compiler will generate). (Also things starting with `__` in gcc/clang at least)

C++ also has namespaces so `namespace::class::thing(int)` becomes `_Z20namespace5class5thingi`.