# C++ program written in C style doesn't compile with C compiler

Tags: c++, c, function, overloading

I'm a student, starting to learn C++ with some previous C knowledge. I have a working C++ code written in C style, that has an oveloaded function for input either a `double` or a `string`:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "ctype.h"

const int STR_LEN = 7;
int try_to_input(double* real_number);
int try_to_input(char (*string)[STR_LEN]);//line 16

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

int try_to_input(double* real_number) {//line 35
    int attempts_for_input = 3;
    //stops when == 0
    while (attempts_for_input) {
        //if input unsuccessful
        if (scanf_s("%lf", real_number) == 0) {
            puts("Invalid input! Try again.");
            attempts_for_input--;
            //flush stdin
            int tmp;
            while ((tmp = getchar()) != EOF && tmp != '\n');
            //extra '\n' after that for some reason
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int try_to_input(char (*string) [STR_LEN] ) { //line 53
    int attempts_for_input = 3;

    while (attempts_for_input) {
        if (gets_s(*string, STR_LEN) == NULL) {
            puts("Invalid input! Try again.\n");
            attempts_for_input--;
            //flush stdin
            int tmp;
            while ((tmp = getchar()) != EOF && tmp != '\n');
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

But when I compile it as C, it gives me the following errors:

```
(16): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
(35): warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration
(53): error C2084: function 'int try_to_input(double *)' already has a body
(35): note: see previous definition of 'try_to_input'
```

---

What could be the problem? What's wrong with my overloading?

Comment: Isn't this a clue that C doesn't support overloaded functions?

Comment: oh, well, I guess

Comment: You cannot write a C program in C++! They are different languages. Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: `#include "stdio.h"` etc should be `#include <stdio.h>` so the compiler will look in the default location instead of the local folder.

Comment: `(strcmp( gender, "female") || strcmp(gender, "male"))` will always be true, since `strcmp` returns `0` when the string is the same, and it will always mismatch at least one of the two.

Comment: Also 'true' doesn't exists in C. Define it to 1.

Comment: I should've thought of overloaded functions in C, sorry. Fixed completely, all works. Also, there's no "true" and "false" in C by default, and NULL is not an integer. And, thanks for the tip Vane!

Comment: Removed irrelevant parts of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a working C++ code written in C style, that has an oveloaded function [..]

Stop it right there!

C does *not* support function overloading, thus the compilation error. Read more in [Does C support overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)

Comment: I will upvote, but I should give credit to the guy who answered that in the comments like a year ago. Thanks for the link, though

Comment: @Sam the question popped up in the questions' feed when you answered, and I didn't check the comments, nor the post date.

Comment: Sure. But turns out it's a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathon Reinhart commented, turns out, C language simply does not support *overloaded functions*.

Comment: I'm confused whether I should accept my answer or wait for John

Comment: You should always select the answer that best answers your question (even if it's your own). Comments are often abused for answers, which not what they are intended for, so you can safely ignore them when selecting an answer.