# Why main function is called in two ways in C?

Tags: c

The `main` function can be called in the following ways in C:

```c
int main()
```

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

[Does C support overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading)
Answer to this question is a NO.

Then how can `main()` be called in C in two ways?

Comment: There can only be one form of main() in a specific program. Which forms that are valid on a given system are determined by the compiler, not by the programmer.

Comment: The first version actually should be `int main(void)`. An empty parameter list in function definitions is a deprecated feature.

Comment: Observe that since only one function is special in this way, a compiler can handle it easily by silently transforming a definition of `int main(void)` into `int main(int _Hidden_argc, char *_Hidden_argv[])`. Then, even if the ABI does not work with routines called with more arguments than parameters in their definitions, it will not matter since `main` is effectively always defined with two parameters (as shown above) and is called that way (by the run-time startup code). The implementation can similarly transform any calls to `main`.