# Does C has function overrides?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function overloading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c)

So I wonder if we can use something like  `void A(){}` and `void A(int b){}` in same code file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not function **overriding**, but function **overloading**.

Anyway no, C doesn't provide it.

The rationale (well, one of them, the one I prefer) is that to provide function overloading you should find a way to give a symbol to a function based also on its parameters, not only on its name.
This would cause a few problems that a low-level language as C wouldn't take.

Comment: Just manually mangle the function's name. Pretend you're a C++ complier.