# How do I write a genric display function in C to display void pointers of all data types?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I've been using void pointers to implement stacks using arrays. I know that before displaying the value pointed to by the void pointer, we need to cast it to suitable data type.

This is my stack structure

```
typedef struct {
    void **arr;   // array stack
    int size;    // size of the stack
    int top;    // top most element of the stack
    int count; // number of elements in the stack
} stack_T;
```

Say I've an int stack ( contents of stack -> arr is of data type int )
now. To display it's contents I can simply write a display()

```
void displayIntStack( stack_T *stack ) { 
    while ( !isEmpty( stack )) {
        printf( "%d ", *( int * )stack -> arr[ stack -> top] );
        pop( stack ); 
    }
}
```

I can call it using `displayIntStack( stack );` and it'll display the contents of the int stack.

**If I want to implement more generic display() function to display the stack contents of all data types without the need to write separate functions. How would I do it?**

Comment: Until C11 there was nothing to do what you are attempting. C11 introduced the `_Generic()` macro that, to a limited degree, allows for declaring options for handing each type you provide a definition for. Other than that, there isn't this type of type-overloading or deduction in C. C++ provides that ability.

Comment: I get it now.Thank you, @DavidC.Rankin!

Comment: Here is a link with a with discussion on `_Generic()` [Generics for multiparameter C functions in C11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17302913/3422102). Given its awkwardness in use -- I never found much use for it...

Comment: When I started with C, I always thought why would anyone ever need C++?! C has got everything ( naive me ). I know now why. I guess I'll just use C++.

Comment: C will do anything you need (and fast), C++ may make doing what you need quicker to develop to avoid writing the additional code, but at the cost of compile-time complexity, memory use and overhead. Don't get me wrong, there is a lot of nicities in C++ containers and overloading -- but there is a reason the Linux kernel is written in C `:)`

Comment: IMO, users tend to need a customize-able print.  For `double`, a generic format would be `"%.17g"`, but that may be unsatisfactory when printing, say Voltage, (prefer engineering units), money (yes I know the issues with FP & money) or  ...

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to implement more generic display() function to display the stack contents of all data types without the need to write separate functions. How would I do it?

Add a member to `stack_T` that is a function pointer that does the printing.  Set that `.print()` member when defining the stack instance.

```
typedef struct {
    void **arr;
    int size;
    int top;
    int count;
    int (*print)(void *);
} stack_T;

while (!isEmpty(stack)) {
   stack->print(stack->arr[stack->top]);
   pop(stack); 
}
```

You can provide a predefined set of `.print()` functions for `int, double` and the [usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To).  This approach lets the user create custom print functions for any type.

---

I'd also expect a way to *apply* this `.print()` to the `stack` without changing the stack.

Further: I think the best approach is to form an *apply* function for your `stack` type and negating the need for a `.print()` function member:

Pseudo code

```
int stack_apply(const stack_T *st, int (*f)(void *state, void *data), void *state) {
  for each node i in the stack
    int result = f(state, stack->arr[i]);
    if (result) return result;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now when you want to print:

```
stack_apply(st, my_print_function, my_print_state);
```

Or maybe a search function, or a max function, or a standard deviation function ....

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

From [C17 standard document](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), Generic selection (6.5.1.1, page number: 56-57):

You can use type-generic expression:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), \
long double: cbrtl, \
default: cbrt, \
float: cbrtf \
)(X)
```

Let's assume, there are these functions :
displayIntStack(stack,int), displayFloatStack(stack,float),  displayCharStack(stack, char).

Then, we define one function displayStack(stack,type) in the main().

```
#define displayStack(stack,type)  _Generic((type), int: displayIntStack, float: displayFloatStack, char:displayCharStack)(stack,type)

int main() {
displayStack(stack,1); // calls displayIntStack
displayStack(stack,1.2f); // calls displayFloatStack
displayStack(stack,'c'); // calls char:displayCharStack
  
}
```

**Another way : Using macro function**

```
#define displayStack(stack_T *stack, T) \
{                                       \
    while (!isEmpty(stack))             \
    {                                   \
        printf("%d ", *(T *)stack->arr[stack->top]);\
        pop(stack);                                   \
    }                                                 \
}

displayStack(stack_T *stack, int) ; // For integer data
displayStack(stack_T *stack, float) ; // for float data
displayStack(stack_T *stack, double) ; // For double data
displayStack(stack_T *stack, char) ; // For char data
```

Comment: Yes, but the point being you still have to write `displayIntStack` and `displayFloatStack` and `displayCharStack`.

Comment: Agree. But this method comes, close to the solution (I think)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  What do you think of the second method, I mentioned

Comment: That's getting closer, but the downside is you end up with the entire `stack` (or whatever data structure you are using) written as a macro instead of code. That brings in all the inherent limitations (and name collisions) you can have with macros. `_Generic()` is fine for simple things like a generic `puts()`, etc.. You really stumble into the limitations when you attempt to make complex data handling generic. (kind of a "round-peg" "square-hole" deal) But don't get me wrong -- my hat is off to you for the effort. If you look at Linux kernel code -- a lot looks that way `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe void pointer ? It will allow you to pass pointer to any kind of type;) then just parse and print the value hidden behind pointer

Comment: Nope, a void pointer points to an incomplete type until cast. Doesn't help.

Comment: I agree with @DavidC.Rankin. I don't think that would work!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I write a generic display function in C to display void pointers of all data types?

You cannot do that reliably, unless your display function is given some way of display values. And mostly because C types are not known at run-time (they are [erased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)): the same sequence of bits could be a `char*` string or some array of `double`-s (perhaps even inside some `union`). Consider perhaps learning [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) which has a stricter and somehow safer type system (and retain some type information at runtime).

BTW, you could store inside your "generic" `stack_T` both the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) and the [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) pointed values. Then you could have, with some coding pain, one less indirection by using [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). This might be more efficient (in some cases) because of your [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

A possibility might be to pass a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) to your display function. You could for example pass as argument a function pointer displaying the pointed values.

Declare first (for readability) a signature

```
 typedef void element_display_sigt (void*displayed_data);
```

Then declare your displaying function to take such a function pointer

```
 void display_stack(stack_T *stack, element_display_sigt*dispfun);
```

Actually, what you dream of are [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). They don't exist in C17. Check by reading [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) (a draft C standard) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

In practice, your `element_display_sigt` would often take an extra argument, for example a `FILE*` to write to. And your `display_stack` would also have that extra argument.

FWIW, closures exist (and also [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) in [modern C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), in [Scheme](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/), in [Common Lisp](https://lisp-lang.org/), in Ocaml, in [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), in [Lua](https://lua.org/). I heard that future C standards might add anonymous functions to C.

You could consider embedding an interpreter like [Lua](https://lua.org/) or [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) (a nice Scheme implementation) in your application coded in C.

You might be interested in reading the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), about [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), and about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

If you code for Linux, be aware of [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) : in some cases, it might be worthwhile to generate the C code of some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) at runtime, then compile that code into a [shared object library](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf), then use that `dlopen`-ed plugin or shared object at runtime. My [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example shows that this can be done thousands of times. Another possibility might be to use machine code generation libraries like [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

Be also aware that [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) specifically still has (at end of 2020) a way of [customizing `printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html)

Another approach is to generate some (printing) C code at build time, with tools inspired from [SWIG](http://swig.org/). You could either write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) generating printing code or, using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), write your own C code generator.