# How to define function that will called with or without parameters?

Tags: c

I need to develop a function in C that will be called with the same definition with or without parameters like this:

```
char *fnc(???) 
{
    char *str;
    ....
    return str;
}
char *c1 = fnc();
char *c2 = fnc(param);
```

How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c

Comment: If you were using `C++` you could do it using default parameters, declaring `char *fnc( my_type my_param = my_default )`. But, alas, C does not do this. It would be a nice addition to the ANSI C standard, if they cared enough. :)

Comment: You guys are giving up on the OP and pushing him to C++.    http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/47291-printf-like-function.html

Comment: @Jim I'm not "pushing" anyone anywhere. I was just sayin... ;) And as indicated in other answers, function overloading, variable parameters (like with `printf`) and default parameters are all different things. Variable parameters requires at least one parameter, which doesn't satisfy the OP's example.

Comment: Without at least one argument, what will tell you how many arguments there are?  Do you mean to communicate via globals or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [Function Overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading) You can't do it in C

Comment: Or **default parameters**, also not available in C.

Comment: Yes you can.  See printf().

Comment: There's a lot of 'you cannot do in C' that people actually do, like oop =)

Comment: @Jim, printf isn't overloaded, it's a variadic function.

Comment: @Vicky  by 'it' I interpreted the goal of the OP, not Function Overloading per se.  #define function()  function(default_value) ??

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko actually you *can* do OOP in C. C++ simply makes OOP a bit easier to do.

Comment: @Jim variadic functions **must have at least one non-optional argument** (C99 Standard section 7.16.1 states that the syntax for optional arguments is `, ...` including the comma, so ISO-compliant compilers won't know how to handle `f(...)` or `f(, ...)`

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko this is one case where the C standard prohibits such behavior: "Different entities designated
by the same identiﬁer either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces" (section 6.2.1)

Comment: @Jim while that macro permits `function()` calls, that macro actually breaks `function(1)` or `function(any_value)`

Comment: you may achieve something similar to function overloading with macros

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve exactly what you want in C.

You do have some options available:

- declare your function as a varargs function and use the va_ macros to access the optional parameters (note that in this case you need to have at least one fixed - non-optional - argument, and you also need to know the types of the remaining arguments you are passed)
- use a variadic macro definition to wrap the function name and call the real function as needed - you'd still need to make the real function variadic, but variadic macros don't require a fixed argument first.

If either of these sound helpful I can elucidate with examples.

Comment: no, you don't need to make the real function variadic

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using the old `varargs.h`
There you have

```
void varfunc( va_alist )
va_dcl
{
     va_list args;
     char    *p1;

     va_start( args );
     p1 = va_arg( args, char * );  /* any type is possible */
     ...
     va_end( args );
}
```

Using the modern `stdarg.h`, it's not possible anymore. You can define function with variable arguments, but you must always have one fixed as it is:

```
void varfunc( int fixedArg, ... )  // of course fixedArg can be of any type 
{
     va_list  args;
     char     *p1;


     va_start( args, fixedArg );  // here you need the fixed one
     p1 = va_arg( args, char * ); // again any type i possible
     ...
     va_end( args );
}
```

There is a quite obvious reason why a syntax with no fixed arguments doesn't make sense: as there is no portable way to determine how many and what type of arguments have been passed, you need that information in a fixed argument, which is e.g. the format string in the `printf()` family or maybe just a number of arguments, some bit flags or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Use `C++` rather than `C`, or pass a `NULL` pointer:

```
void fnc(char* Optional)
{
    if (Optional != NULL)
    {
       // do something amazing
    }
}

fnc(NULL); // "Not passing" a parameter
fnc("hello");
```

Comment: "I need to develop a fucntion in C language...."

Comment: The answer is in C. The only part that isn't is that bit that says "Use C++ **OR**"

Answer (score 1):

In C you can't do that directly, you'd have to go through a macro. Variable argument macros are different from variable argument functions because they allow the argument to be empty. Then you have to detect if the argument is in fact empty and to provide a default argument to the final function call.

I have a macro package [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) that does all that wrapping for you. One possibility would be to declare something like

```
#define fnc(...) P99_CALL_DEFARG(fnc_imp, 1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define fnc_defarg_0() (char const*)0

void fnc_imp(char const* arg) {
  if (!arg) {
    /* do something special */
  }
  /* your code */
}
```

Note that in C a macro may have the same name as a function, if you don't find that confusing, so you could even name the function itself `fnc`, too.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to solve the problem is to recognise that you shouldn't be using one function for 2 different cases in the first place; as this is mostly pointless and creates code maintenance problems (e.g. makes it hard to detect "wrong number of arguments" bugs).

For example, you could have a `foo_simple(void)` that (internally) calls `foo_complex(arg1, arg2)`; where other code can use whichever function makes them happy.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of misguided answers here.  What you want is like printf, which can take 0 arguments, or it can take many.  To mimick this, you use the ... specifier in the function.

```
 function variableArguments(void * typeDefinition, ...);
```

you can cast the void * to whatever you want, even if its not a pointer by passing in the address of a non pointer value.

Comment: printf and other varargs functions need a minimum of 1 parameter

Comment: But you will always have at least one argument

Comment: You can cast away that argument though if you have an identifier that specifies not to use it.  It would be in the switch statement or the while loop as you go through the argument list.

Comment: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/47291-printf-like-function.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of things:

## 1:

```
#define function() function(NULL)
void function(void * parameter)
{
    if (parameter != NULL)
    { /*code*/ }
}
```

## 2:

```
void function(void * parameter)
{
    if (parameter != NULL)
    { /*code*/ }
}
call: func(NULL); or func(ptr);
```

## 3:

```
use a va_list
```

## 4:

i'm unsure if C handles this or not, but you /may/ be able to use default parameters

```
void function(void * parameter = NULL)
{
     if (parameter != NULL)
     { /*code*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, this is easy:

```
char *fnc(parameter=default_value){
....
}
```

So, if you call to the function without parameters, the value of the function parameter will be the "default_value". If you call to the function with a parameter, the value of the function parameter will be the one in the function call. If you have more than 1 parameter, don't forget to put the parameter with a default value at the end of the parameter list!

BTW, sorry for my bad english and if I'm wrong, tell me, please. I'm a programming aprentice :-)