# More than one instance overloaded function has C linkage

Tags: c++, cuda

Following the sample code in CUDA samples about C++ integration I was writing the wrapper functions that call CUDA code in a `.cu` file.

In that file I have a function that initializes CUDA context and allocates global memory and puts some data in constant memory.

```
extern "C" void initEngine(int *d_data, int *d_coefA, int *d_coefB)
{
   //Allocations
   //Copy to constant memory
}
```

Now what I want to do is overload that `initEngine` function to receive to more parameters but I think there's no way to overload that function as it has **C linkage** am I right?

```
extern "C" void initEngine(int *d_data, int *d_coefA, int *d_coefB, int *d_coefC, 
                           int *d_random)
{
   //Allocations
   //Copy to constant memory
}
```

Could you give me some advise to have only one `initEngine` function? or is not possible and I have to have 2 functions or probably have only one function with all the parameters and just pass NULL references or something like that.

Comment: Why not make your own overloaded C++ function, that calls initEngine in the ways you want?

Comment: You mean, before calling any function in my `.cu` file (which has only extern "C" functions) create a function that checks the parameters and then calls the correct initEngine in the .cu file? I thought about that but I was trying to find a way (if possible) to do everything on the .cu file side. Thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: I don't know anything about CUDA so I can't help too much but you can't overload a C function, sorry :(

Comment: Why not get rid of the `extern "C"` declarations? You can just use C++ in your .cu file.

Comment: Can I just get rid of them and everything should work fine? I mean, I am using them because thats what I saw in the C++ integration sample from Nvidia. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, overloading is a C++ feature.

If you want to have overloaded functions that are callable from other modules, use C++ throughout (i.e. don't use `extern "C"`, and keep all your files as .cpp or .cu).

If you don't wish to do that, you could try resorting to [macros or some other magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c).

Comment: Well getting rid of the `extern "C"` let indeed overload the function, but then... why/when would I need to use the `extern "C"` trick? was it used in previous versions of CUDA? I'll check again the C++ integration example.

Comment: `extern "C"` is used whenever you want to have a C++ compiled module linked with a C compiled module.  The linkage structures are different, so `extern "C"` instructs the c++ linker to use c-style linkage, so that the C module and C++ module can interact.  This is a C/C++ question and has nothing to do with CUDA, or which version of CUDA you are using.

Comment: Ok I see, . I agree is not a CUDA question but as I saw it on the CUDA samples and I was using it in a CUDA app I thought it was related to some feature in early CUDA versions, but now I know. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't address OP's concern, but I ran into this same issue myself when trying to link with cublas in C++ code. Instead of including `cublas.h`, I solved the problem with

`#include <cublas_v2.h>`