# C Function Overloading

Tags: c++, c

Isn't the answer is "A" because function overloading isn't allowed in C?

More than one function in the same file may
have the same name:

A. never in C and only if their signatures are
unambiguously different in C++.

B. only if they are all declared static.

C. if all but 1 are declared static or const.

D. only if no external variables are used.

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is A. But I don't know what does _unambiguously different signatures_ mean.

Comment: The answer is A, also because all the others don't make sense in any way.

Comment: @rodrigo: working backwards from the assumption that the answer is correct, it must mean for example that `void foo(int)` is unambiguously different from `void foo(long)`, whereas `void foo(int)` is not unambiguously different from `void foo(int32_t)` in all implementations because those might be the same type. But I think the word "unambiguous" is redundant: two function signatures are either different or they're not :-)

Comment: In the context of overloading, `int foo(int)` and `void foo(int)` are different but not unambiguously different, since using both will cause an ambiguous overload error.  So that's probably what its trying to say.  But I agree the term *unambiguously different* is itself ambiguous.

Comment: @rodrigo: I think it means the data types of the parameter(s) and/or return type(s) are different between the functions.

Comment: @JackieDalen: Only that the return type is not used in C++ overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't support overloading.

In C++, keywords `static` and `const`<sup>*</sup> can not effect on overloading.

Then *A* is the answer.

---

<sup>*</sup> Not `const` for constant member functions inside a class declaration to make `this` pointer a const.

Comment: It is now possible to overload functions using `__Generic`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/how-to-achieve-function-overloading-in-c), for example.