# Is it possible multiple methods with the same name but different parameters in a class?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I've coded in C before, but I'm completely new to java
I'm doing a tutorial for my OOP class, and this is pretty much my first time officially learning the language

In the tutorial, my professor made a class that will be used to test an I/O helper class that I have to make myself *(and btw, the tutorial is (a) optional and (b) not for marks, so I'm not cheating or anything by making this thread... and (c) I've never used java before whereas a lot of my other classmates have, so I'm behind).*

ANYWAY. In his testing class that he made, he calls a method "getInt" that I need to put into my I/O helper class.

However when he calls the getInt method, he sometimes uses 3 parameters, sometimes 2, sometimes none, etc.

I know in C I wouldn't be able to do that (right?), but is it possible to do in Java? And if so, how?

Comment: See [Overloaded Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html): "The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and *Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures [but the same name]*. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists.." (Java is not C.)

Comment: Also, note that overloading is *not related* to "OOP" - not all OOP languages support overloading, and some languages with overloading are not OOP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading) (or Function overloading) is legal in C++ and in Java, but only if the methods take a different arguments (i.e. do different things). You can't overload in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c).

Answer (score 12):

Yes it is legal.  It is called *method overloading*.  It is decribed in the Oracle Java Tutorial - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Here's how you might implement a class with an overloaded `getInt` method.

```
    public class Foo {
        ...
        public int getInt(String s1) {
            // get and return an int based on a single string.
        }

        public int getInt(String s1, int dflt) {
            // get and return an int based on a string and an integer
        }
    }
```

Typically (!) you need to put different stuff in the method bodies, to do what is required.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply!! 

My problem is that I have my helper class that's pretty much done, but it only works for when the prof has included all 3 parameters. For all of the other instances there are those red Eclipse X's and it's telling me that my parameters don't match.

How do I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but it *sounds* like *you* need to implement all of the overloads of the `getInt` method in your class ... that his helper class is calling.