# Java - can you create a helper class with methods with same name but possibly can take diff arguments

Tags: java

looking for some help...
In Java - i am trying to find if i can have a helper class which basically has several methods:

```
 class helper{
method1(){doing something}
method2(){doing something}
method_important(String a, String b){doing something}
method_important(String a, int b, String b){doing something}
}
```

Notably i want to call helper class with method_important from other classes but want a flexiblity to pass desired arguments as i it can be two strings or i may have to pass String, int, String....
is it even possible? if no? what is best way to achieve it?
Problem is from my other methods i need to pass different type of variables..

Comment: I don't think you need a helper class, you can just overload your methods. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058166/is-it-possible-multiple-methods-with-the-same-name-but-different-parameters-in-a it might help.

Comment: As shared in your code, method overloading is the best way to achieve what you want to do. And as it seems you've already done it..

Comment: java provides method overloading to achieve this functionality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598166/java-method-overloading)

Answer (score 1):

Although, the best way and suitable to you is using **Method Overloading** (specially in case where arguments have different data types).
But in case and just in case , if you have several methods where type of arguments is same but the number of arguments different (which can be a probable case), Why not use **Varags** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html

You can use a combination of both Method overloading and varags in you helper class.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly posible in Java, and it is called method overloading. Check this out https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java