# static_if in C99's preprocessor

Tags: c, c99, c-preprocessor, static-if

Is it possible to implement static_if in C99?

```
#define STATIC_IF(COND, ...) \
     if (COND) MACRO1(__VA_ARGS__); \
     else MACRO2(__VA_ARGS__);
```

How can I properly implement `STATIC_IF(…)` in here? Depending on `COND` the arguments either should be passed to `MACRO1` or `MACRO2`, but the arguments for both macros look differently. `COND` is statically testable, something like `sizeof (…) > 42`.

- `#if COND` then `#define STATIC_IF MACRO1` … wouldn't work for my use case.
- I cannot use compiler specific solutions.

Comment: This is not possible - your only chance is to get around with `#if` directives.

Comment: I hoped that there was some magic like what is used in Boost or P99 to solve my question. I'll keep the question open for a while. Maybe someone comes up with a solution, though I am not really confident.

Comment: What is the concrete scenario requiring this? Be more specific!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I want to call a different functions depending on the number of arguments. I get the number of arguments with `(sizeof ((_Bool[]) { 0, __VA_ARGS__ }) / sizeof (_Bool) - 1) > …`. I though I could have this expression evaluated, so I can use `MACRO ## EVALUATED_COND(__VA__ARGS__)`.

Comment: @Kay, if it is just the number of arguments that makes the difference between the two cases, then sure P99 could do this, without refering to `sizeof` expressions, just in the preprocessor. There are `P99_NARG` and `P99_IF_LT` that could be used for this. But as always for this type of questions it would be much more helpful if you'd be more specific and describe exactly what your intent is, not only what you think is your technical limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, because a condition like `sizeof(something)>42` is not static for the preprocessor. The preprocessor is purely textual (in principle, except for arithmetic). It does not know about C or types.

Notice that expression of the [condition in `#if`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html) is severely constrained.

However, you could use build tricks. For instance, you might have a standalone program like

```
 // generate-sizeof.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "foo-header.h"

 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    const char* headername = NULL;
    if (argc<2) 
      { fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing header name\n", argv[0]); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    headername = argv[1]; 
    FILE *fh = fopen(headername, "w");
    if (!fh) { perror(headername); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    fprintf(fp, "// generated file %s\n", headername);
    fprintf(fp, "#define SIZEOF_charptr %d\n", (int) sizeof(char*));
    fprintf(fp, "#define SIZEOF_Foo %d\n", (int) sizeof(Foo));
    fclose (fp);
 }
```

then have a rule like

```
 generated-sizes.h : generate-sizeof foo-header.h
     ./generate-sizeof generated-sizes.h
```

in your `Makefile` etc etc...

So your build machinery will generate the appropriate headers.

<sup>Things become much tricker if you want to cross-compile!</sup>

Then you might have an `#include "generated-sizes.h"` in your header, and later code

```
#if SIZEOF_Foo > 42
#error cannot have such big Foo
#endif
```

Comment: So there is no solution to have `sizeof(something)>42` evaluated to 0 or 1, so I could use `MACRO ## EVALUATED_COND`?

Comment: The preprocessor is not purely textual. It can do some arithmetic and evaluate constant expressions of integral type - this involves integer constants, character constants, and the special `defined` operator.

Answer (score 7):

In your specific case (if I understand your comments correctly), yes, you can do this.

You can't pass `sizeof` to anything in the preprocessor because the preprocessor runs before type information is available. Luckily for you, you don't need `sizeof` to count the number of arguments in a statically-written list ([X-Y alert!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)), so this is no obstacle.

Here's one possible implementation using the [Order](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order) macro library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <order/interpreter.h>

void oneArg(int a) {
    printf("one arg: %d\n", a);
}

void twoArgs(int a, int b) {
    printf("two args: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

void threeArgs(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("three args: %d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}

#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8function_list  \
ORDER_PP_CONST(("unused")            \
               (oneArg)              \
               (twoArgs)             \
               (threeArgs))

#define SelectFunction(...) ORDER_PP (                                 \
    8seq_at(8tuple_size(8((__VA_ARGS__))), 8function_list)  \
)

#define Overloaded(...) SelectFunction(__VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(void) {
    Overloaded(42);
    Overloaded(42, 47);
    Overloaded(42, 47, 64);
    return 0;
}
```

(This simple case indexes a list by the number of arguments - probably not exactly what you want to do, but enough to get the idea. Order does provide a full range of complex, nonevaluating control structures - `if`, `cond`, `match`, etc. - for more complex decision-making.)

Order is pretty heavyweight: I assume you can do something similar with the much lighter and more realistically-portable P99 (not familiar with it). Order works very well with GCC and adequately well with Clang (Clang will choke on deep recursion or long loops); *it* is standard, but not all compilers are.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, not in the sense you mean.

But: I would just go ahead, and trust that an optimizing compiler notices that the condition is always true (or false) and does the right thing, i.e. optimizes out the test.

You might need to force some optimization to provoke the compiler into doing this.

Comment: My problem is that I'll have a type error if the wrong macro is used. E.g. MACRO1 gets a float, the other one a string. (I know, this sounds like I'm choosing the wrong approach to a non-existant problem, but it would be nice to know if I can emulate a static_if in C.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can remove the restriction of having to stick to C99, there is a better solution to this problem built-in to the language since C11:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(float x, double y, float * z) {
  printf("inside f1\n");
}

void f2(int x, _Bool * y) {
  printf("inside f2\n");
}

#define STATIC_IF(COND, ...) _Generic(&(int[(!!(COND))+1]){ 0 }, \
    int(*)[2]: f1, \
    int(*)[1]: f2) \
  (__VA_ARGS__)


int main(void) {
  float fl;
  _Bool b;

  STATIC_IF(sizeof(double) > 4, 0.0f, 1.0, &fl);
  STATIC_IF(sizeof(double) > 128, 16, &b);
}
```

The `_Generic` operator performs a compile-time selection based on a type. Since it selects based on a type, it's also the only language-level expression that can accept conflicting types of "argument", since its very purpose is to resolve a value of the right type based on inputs.

This means you can easily use it to choose between your two functions with incompatible signatures, because it will completely ignore the type of the one that isn't chosen by matching the input; the arguments (applied to whichever function `_Generic` returns) will only be checked against the successful match.

Although `_Generic` is designed to dispatch on types, not values, any integer constant expression can be "turned into" a type by using it as the size of an array. So in the above macro we create an anonymous array (n.b. this is *not* a VLA), of count either 2 (for true) or 1 (for false) and dispatch against the type of the pointer to that array in order to resolve which of the two incompatible functions to use.

This will certainly reduce to nothing at runtime, since not only is the condition static, but the alternative "execution path" wouldn't even type check and thus can't have code generated for it in the first place.