# Function overloading of main in c

Tags: c

The C Language doesn't support function overloading [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c) because there is no name mangling in C.

But C allows one to write both

```
int main ()
```

and

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
```

When defining the main function.
Isn't this function overloading?

Comment: I'm guessing the first declaration should be `int main()` or `int main(void)`?

Comment: I suppose you meant `int main()` rather than `int main` to think that it is function overloading? `int main;` is variable and not function.

Comment: The C standard says that the implementation doesn't declare any prototype for `main`, and that it shall be defined with a return type of `int` and no arguments (`int main(void) {}`) **or** two arguments (`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}`) (or in some other implementation-defined manner). Whichever form you pick, it will be _the_ `main` of your program. For your reference, this is described in section 5.1.2.2.1 ("Program startup").

Answer (score 4):

This is not overloading, because you can't have both a no-arg `main` and a 2-arg `main` in the same program. Overloading `main` would require there to be two versions of `main` in the same program with different signatures, where which one is executed would be determined... somehow.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not function overloading, as the first declaration declares a variable while the second declaration declares a function.

Comment: I meant the first one to be a function call. Edited now.