# Getters in C with const parameters

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Let's say I have a function:

```
t_list *get_first_matching(t_list *head_of_list, <some other stuff>);
```

This function would retrieve an element from the given list and I would be able to modify it.

But if I have something like this:

```
void print_matching(const t_list *head_of_list)
{
    const matching_elemnt = get_first_matching(head_of_list, <other stuff>);
    <print the element>
}
```

The compiler will say that that I can't pass a constant pointer to that function.

What I could do, is copy paste that function, adding const:

```
const t_list *get_first_matching(const t_list *head_of_list, <some other stuff>);
```

Can I make only one function that would work with const parameters and would also work in case I would need to modify the retrieved element?

Is there a solution without warnings or without const cast?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/function-overloading-in-c/25026358#25026358

Comment: ^ Dan link is a very suitable solution to handle this case in C.

Comment: Paste complete error messages. I made a version of your code and it compiled, although with warnings.

Comment: Why does `get_first_matching()` take a `t_list *head_of_list` instead of a `const t_list *head_of_list`?  Certainly, it does not modify the list elements.

Comment: but the returned element has to be const, which I can't modify (if I need to, in other functions) without a const cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 approaches:

1. Form a `t_list *get(const t_list *, ...)` much like standard C functions `char *strstr(const char *s1, ...);` with a similar issue.  Even though `s1` points to `const` data and the value returned is a pointer to an element in `s1`, the function returns a non-`const` pointer.  This is common practice in C.
2. Form 2 getter functions.  It is easy to make one a wrapper of the other.

   ```
   const t_list *get_const(const t_list *, ...) {
     ...
   } 

   t_list *get(t_list *, ...) {
     return (t_list *) get_const(t_list *, ...);
   }
   ```

I prefer #2.  As `const` did not appear in original C, solution #1 was the best way to wedge `const` into existing code.  Yet OP's is making new code and so the #2 option is available.

---

A 3rd sample C11 approach: use `_Generic`.
`_Generic` selects which function to use.  This approach must be taken **with caution**.  The fine details of `_Generic` still need work, IMO.  The "hiding" of functions is disconcerting for some and `_Generic` is easy to employ incorrectly.  Note the `getnext(s)` example below evaluates `s` twice, but once is with `_Generic(s)`, a compile time evaluation.

```
char *getnext_nonconst(char *s) {
  return s + 1;
}

const char *getnext_const(const char *s) {
  return s + 1;
}

#define getnext(s) _Generic((s), \
    char *: getnext_nonconst, \
    const char *: getnext_const \
    ) (s)

int main(void) {
  char *ncs = (char []){"chux is amazing"};
  ncs = getnext(ncs);  // getnext_nonconst() is called
  const char *cs = "but not perfect";
  cs = getnext(cs);    // getnext_const() is called
}
```

Comment: now that you mention it, strstr() really casts `const char*` into `char*`, I thought that's bad practice

Comment: @EmilTerman How `strstr()` "does  it" with a cast or union or who knows what, is an implementation detail that is not a concern.  What is important is that the returned pointer  points into the passed in `s1` and should be treated the same.  C++ fixes this by overloading `strstr()` with multiple functions.  We could do this in C99 with one "function" using macro magic and `_Genric()`.

Comment: #1 approach also used in `strto....()`, `bsearch()`, `memchr()`, `strchr()`, 
 `strrchr()`, many others.

Comment: @EmilTerman  The "bad practice" is casting away `const` when it is not absolutely known that it is OK to do so.  In the case of `t_list *get(t_list *, ...)`, code "knows" it is OK to cast away `const`.

Comment: @Stargateur a bit of French humor, non?

Answer (score 3):

Change your existing function to accept a `const` parameter:

```
t_list *get_first_matching(const t_list *head_of_list, <some other stuff>);
```

This is the only version you need. When you call this with a non-const parameter, it will be implicitly converted to const.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to modify the retrieved element without a cast to const.

Comment: @EmilTerman So you are saying that your question is missing some important details. Please edit your question to provide these.

Comment: c doesn't allow that

Comment: @EmilTerman C doesn't allow what? You need to show more code. Your original question does not show anything about your list data structure. Nothing from your original questions shows why you cannot just return `t_list*` while accepting a `const t_list*` parameter.

Comment: for example this will compile with a warning: https://gist.github.com/TermanEmil/c2bc73e1d13ec126a5a68479f70d1f82

Comment: @EmilTerman C allow asm... C allow everything but doesn't guaranty that will do what you want.

Comment: Is worth asking why you're motivated to return to the caller the same list that was passed as an argument.  Without dot notation, chaining functions like in JavaScript won't work.  The caller already knows the pointer passed in, I don't see why it would have to be returned.  If they're in fact different, as looks like it would be the case from your declaration, then they don't have to match in constancy.  Lol, never used that work on SO before ;)

Comment: @DanFarrell I'm sorry, I didn't get that

Comment: Non const to const is safe and is only bad practice to do explicitly because it can happen automatically.  Const to non const breaks the const contract and turns the value of const into misinformation.

Comment: @DanFarrell By the name get_first_matching(), does some kind off search which potentially can return a pointer to the first element. However, I find it difficult to believe that it will simply return the given parameter directly. This is heavily dependent on missing implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

You could (in practice) cast the first argument, e.g.

`matching_elemnt = get_first_matching((const t_list *)head_of_list,` *other stuff* `);`

However, the `get_first_matching` function has (if it is a genuine getter function) probably the wrong declaration and definition. I feel its first argument should be `const t_list*` but you need to decide (and perhaps correct your code, even at all the call sites)...

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to cast into const?

Comment: @EmilTerman I think it could trigger some UB to do that. I will never advice to break const by casting. Note that I don't understand why Basile cast to const and not cast a const to a non const...

Comment: Adding const makes a non const pointer const, de-escalating permissions and maintaining the non const contract (which allows but doesn't require changes).  Removing const breaks the contract by adding change permission.  Permission isn't exactly the right word, but the analogy is clear.