# Is there a way to assign a unique number to a type in C?

Tags: c, types

I am coming from a C++ background, and have recently taken up C. I am am having trouble assigning a number to a type (or vice versa); what I need is some way to assign a unique ID to a type, preferably starting from `0`. My goal is to have a function (or macro) that indexes an array based on a passed-in type, which I believe to only be achievable through macros.

Also, since I use the `sizeof()` the type which I need to be passed in, it makes using `enums` as an alternative difficult. If I were to pass the enumerator to the function/macro instead, then I would have to get the type from the number, the exact opposite (but maybe easier) problem.

Is this even possible in C? I have tried researching this question, but have not found any answer to this problem particularly, which I was able to do in C++ with templates, like so:

```
int curTypeIdx = 0;

template <typename T>
struct TypeHandle {
    static int const val;
}

template <typename T>
int const TypeHandle<T>::val = curTypeIdx++;
```

The reason for this is that I am building an ECS. I have an `EntityManager` struct, which is supposed to contain arrays of components. Since I plan for this to be general-purpose, I defined an upper limit of components (`MAX_COMPONENTS`) and have an array of `char*`s of length `MAX_COMPONENTS`. At a basic level, The goal is to give the user of the `EntityManager` the ability to define their own components, and store them in these generic arrays.

If there is any other way to

Thank you all for any advice.

Comment: Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: The macro also uses the sizeof that type for casting, so if I use an enum I would have to do the opposite: get a type from a number index. I'll edit the original post to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a number to a type"? Can you maybe show an example of how you would do that in C++?

Comment: I edited the post to demonstrate a simplified but working solution.

Comment: you could define your types in the same file, and use `__LINE__` (current line number) as the unique ID. can you show us what you want to achieve in C?

Comment: Can you show what you *actually* want to do ("function that indexes array based on type")? Maybe your approach isn't quite the way to go. (Otherwise, is this what you want to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/how-to-achieve-function-overloading-in-c)

Comment: No as the C types do not have constructors. @Jean-FrançoisFabre there is a difference between compile and run time type number.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You are trying to solve problem X and have solution Y in your head that is incomplete. You are now asking a question about Y when there is likely another solution Z to your problem that better fits with the tools available in the C language. Please provide more information about the original problem X that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to edit the post to give a more general idea of what I want to do, in case there is a better way.

Comment: I just looked back at my old code and saw that I defined the value outside of the class. Is it still invalid/undefined behavior? It worked fine with my old project.

Comment: How portable does the code have to be? Can you use something GCC specific?

Comment: I am using GCC, so that would be fine.

Comment: @mrFoobles: Consider using the [constructor function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are OK with enumerating ALL supported types once( and update the list if language comes up with new types), then you can use the stringize functionality of C macros and an array of strings to achieve what you want.

```
#define GET_TYPE_ID(type) get_type_id(#type)
const char *type_strings[] = { "char", "unsigned char", "short" /* so on.. */};

int get_type_id(const char* type_string) {
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(type_strings)/sizeof(const char*); i++) {
         if ( strcmp(type_string, type_strings[i]) == 0 ) return i;
    }
    // Should never reach here if you have taken care of all types and 
    // don't pass in illegal types.
}
```

Now you can get an integer ID for each type with `GET_TYPE_ID(int)`, `GET_TYPE_ID(char)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the `#` capability of macros. I could use that to make some sort of "register type" macro.