# C/C++ aliasing functions to other function with different arguments

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

The following is some background as to what I want to do and why. The actual question is at the very bottom...

I have an API that has some format.
For instance

```
int f(void *str1, void *str2) {...}
```

I want to reimplement the system behind the API so that it can be a drop in replacement for the old system. However it turns out that `str1` is now unnecessary and moreover doesn't make sense to have if you're aware that you're using my new system. Therefore, I want to be able to expose the underlying API that makes sense:

```
int f_internal(void *str2);
```

Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
#ifdef  USE_INTERNAL
#define INTERNAL(sym) sym##_internal
#else
#define INTERNAL(sym) sym
#endif

extern "C" {
#ifndef USE_INTERNAL
int f(void *str1, void *str2){
  return INTERNAL(f)(str2);
}
#endif

SOME_ATTRIBUTES
int
INTERNAL(f)(void *str2){
  ... // actual content
} EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO(INTERNAL(f), 1);

}
```

The effect is if I define `USE_INTERNAL`, a call to f(a) works, but I don't define it then we have to use the f(a, b).

The problem I am encountering is that `EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO` itself defines another function name but doesn't evaluate `INTERNAL(F)` first. This results in the message

```
dir: error: pasting ")" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
       INTERNAL(sym) \
--- NOTE--- EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO takes args 'sys' and 'n'
other_dir: note: in definition of macro ‘EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO’
   void _example##sym##_##n(void) {} \
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO:

I want to have a compile flag that can change the number of arguments needed to call something.
Maybe something like (if it existed)

```
using f(a, b) = f_internal(a);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not a simple trampoline function `int f(void *str1, void *str2) { return f_internal(str2); }`? This way, `f()` can be exported as usual.

Comment: At the moment I am confused by `EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO(INTERNAL(F, 1));` which appears to use the INTERNAL macro with 2 arguments?

Comment: Concerning the API: Extra arguments which are not anymore needed wouldn't me concern as much as new arguments which wasn't needed before... ;-)

Comment: @Gem Taylor, that was a typo I fixed it

Comment: Sorry, and capital F?

Comment: Scheff, I have to export the function that does the work, whether it's named `f` or `f_internal`. The trampoline function is the current implementation. The trampoline is the actual function if `USE_INTERNAL` is defined. I would the user to always call `f`, but depending on their understanding of the library they're linking in, they can use `f` with 1 fewer argument, which makes sense in their context.

Comment: capital F typo also fixed.

Comment: And you still get the same errors?

Comment: yes. This above is not my actual code, but a simplified example for stack overflow.

Comment: Why `f_internal`? As this is C++, you could *overload* the two functions: `void f(void* str); void f(void* str, void*) { f(str); }` or simply use a default argument: `void f(void* str, void* = nullptr);`

Comment: Aconcagua, I was wondering if there may be a way to do this in C (note the extern "C" {}), but I think overloading is the way to go.

Comment: @Chris Ah, sorry, overlooked the `extern "C"`...

Comment: So fix your `EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO` to expand the arguments before concatenating them. How is `EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO` related to what you are trying to do? `using f(a, b) = f_internal(a);` - you mean `using f(a, b) = f_internal(b);` right?

Comment: @Chris You might be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479207/how-to-achieve-function-overloading-in-c). You'd have the famous `#ifdef __cplusplus` macros anyway, and you could provide the C-style overloads this way inside an `#else` block...

Comment: @KamilCuk The end result is that I have aliases to functions, which is what I'm trying to do. The implementation I chose doesn't work because of what you mentioned. I don't know how to expand the arguments before concatenating them.

Comment: Ah, correcting my previous post: Default argument is out, as you drop first, not second parameter. Sorry.

Comment: Is the alias meant to have external or internal linkage? You described how your current code does not work. Can you show the code _should_ work with some examples in case the macro USE_INTERAL is defined or not? Is f_internal extern? Can't you just `#define f(a, b) f(b)` ?

Comment: f that calls f_internal has external linkage.

Comment: `but depending on their understanding of the library they're linking in` : If your user understand your library correctly, they would be able to call  the function with another name.

Comment: @Kaenbyou Rin My library has higher performance, and so for that reason I might want to link in this library and not want to change the source code that actually uses the api. If you were building a system from scratch, you would use the "new" API that uses one fewer argument.

Comment: @Chris That is the point. If the user is building something from scratch, they would simply call the function with the new name (e.g. `f2(b)`), while the old code base can continue to use `f(a, b)`. The logic is: if a user is aware that they can call the function with fewer argument, they should also be aware that the function has a different name.

Comment: @Kaenbyou Rin, I see what you mean. I would've liked to keep the name the same, but if that's not a problem in terms of API design, then I suppose I have no problem with. Just wanted to keep everything clean and alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This results in the message

To fix the message let macro arguments expand before concatenating them.

```
#define EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO_X(sys, n) EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO(sys, n)
EXPORT_FUNCTION_MACRO_X(INTERNAL(f), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that with a macro in the C part:

```
#define f(...) CONCAT(f, NUM(__VA_ARGS__, 2, 1)) (__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CC(X, Y)
#define CC(X, Y) X ## Y
#define NUM(X, Y, N, ...) N

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void f_internal(void* str);

// specifically compiled for C or C++ anyway (and most likely inlined)
// -> no need for extern "C" for these:
void f1(void* str) { f_internal(str); }
void f2(void* unused, void* str) { f_internal(str); }
```

The macro `f` would select the correct function out of `f1` and `f2`, which again would call `f_internal` with the correct argument. Works for both C and C++. If you prefer, you could still just provide two overloads for C++ separately and let only the C people deal with the macros.

I doubt one could call that 'elegant'; if you want to qualify as 'ugly' – up to you. But at least it works...

Answer (score 1):

The following code behaves like this:

- If `USE_INTERNAL` is defined, defines an `inline` (c++) / `static` (c) function `int f(void* str)`.
- Otherwise, defines an `inline` (c++) / `static` (c) function `int f(void* str1, void* str2)`.

Both functions are trampolines to the actual (`int f_internal(void* str)`) function.

Note that since the functions are defined in the header, `inline` (c++) / `static` (c) is required to keep them from violating the ODR rule (I am a c++ person, so I don't know any way better than `static` to achieve this in c. If there is, please let me know).

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int f_internal(void* str);

#ifdef USE_INTERNAL

#ifdef __cplusplus
inline
#else
static
#endif
int f(void* str1, void* str2) {
    return f_internal(str2);
}

#else

#ifdef __cplusplus
inline
#else
static
#endif
int f(void* str) {
    return f_internal(str);
}

#endif
```