# C - Method overloading with different struct type arguments using macro

Tags: c, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to achieve method overloading in C, preferably using macros so the header/library can handle the definitions and declarations instead of putting that onto the user. Now I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026358/10305477) about using `_Generic` however the problem is my functions have `struct` types. So there's no way to evaluate their type using a `__typeof__` of `_Generic`. I wonder if there is any way at all.

This is how my header file looks like (which is all we should be concerned with)-

```c
#pragma once

// Macros for generic like use of the data structure

// Macros for the stack type itself
/*
 * Define stack with corresponding type
 * Converts Stack(int) to intstack_t
*/
#define Stack(type) type stack_t

// Macros for functions
/*
 * Define createStack function
 * Converts createStack(int, 5) to create_intstack(5)
*/
#define createStack(type, capacity) create_ ##type ##stack(capacity)

/*
 * Define destroyStack function
 * Converts destroyStack(someIntStack) to destroy_intstack(someIntStack)
 * Where someIntStack is a pointer to a variable of type intstack_t
*/
#define destroyStack(stack) _Generic(stack, intstack_t*: destroy_intstack, charstack_t*: destroy_charstack)(stack)

/*
 * Define push function
 * Converts push(someIntStack, data) to intstack_push(someIntStack, data)
 * Where someIntStack is a pointer to a variable of type intstack_t
*/
#define push(stack, data) _Generic(stack, intstack_t*: intstack_push, charstack_t*: charstack_push)(stack, data)

// Stack structure definition(s)

// int stack definition
typedef struct IntegerStack {
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* arr;
}intstack_t;

// char stack definition
typedef struct CharacterStack {
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char* arr;
}charstack_t;

//Stack functions

// int stack functions
intstack_t* create_intstack(int);
void destroy_intstack(intstack_t*);
void intstack_push(intstack_t*, int);

// char stack functions
charstack_t* create_charstack(int);
void destroy_charstack(charstack_t*);
void charstack_push(charstack_t*, char);
```

Majority of the function declarations (and indirectly, their respective macros) have been removed, as they all essentially function the same. I'm only concerned about the `push` function macro as provided. The other macros are really there to show what kind of usecase I intend. Obviously the macro used in `push` using `_Generic` will not work as `intstack_t` or `charstack_t` are not primitive types.

The goal is for the user to be able to use `push(stack, data)` where the stack can be a variable of either type `intstack_t*` or `charstack_t*` and the statement `push(stack, data)` will be transformed into `intstack_push(stack, data)` or `charstack_push(stack, data)` respectively.

Comment: It may be possible, but it'll probably make your code hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Instead of using a type, use `void *` and store a pointer to an opaque type.

Comment: I really don't want to use void pointers as it might make the code type unsafe and open up serious vulnerabilities. I'm fine with the code being difficult to read/maintain but I do not want it to be unsafe unless explicitly needed

Comment: You've left out the control expression in the `_Generic` invocation. I assume you meant it to be`(stack)`. But why does it matter that the types are not primitive?

Comment: @rici my bad, I did not notice I had the param missing. But it won't work for "intstack_t" or "charstack_t" types because _Generic does not allow those, it only allows primitive types like `int`, `long` etc

Comment: @Chase: Says whom? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tujqfS. (From the C standard, 6.5.2p2: "The type name in a generic association shall specify a complete object type other than a variably modified type." Nothing about primitive types there.)

Comment: Here's a more fun example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bffb6a1ffbd8cfcc

Comment: `clang` seems to throw errors at me that the types are not legal. I don't think it's possible for `_Generic` to know the type of a struct. Even if it is, it sure as hell isn't working for me

Comment: What clang version? Godbolt is using clang-9 there, and it seems perfectly happy. In fact, I worked backwards through the clang version list back to clang-3, and it continued to be happy. Maybe you've got some error in your invocation.

Comment: As that quote from the C standard indicates, you can't use an incomplete type. Which is not surprising, because you can't write a value whose type is incomplete. But you can use a pointer to an incomplete type, since you're allowed to use a value which is a pointer to an incomplete type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_Generic` will work with any complete type other than a Variable Length Array. And although you cannot associate incomplete types with values in an `_Generic` invocation, there is no problem with pointers to incomplete types.

So your `push` macro will work just fine, even if used in a context where `instack_t` and `charstack_t` are opaque.

Sample on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d9b181af2429c5e

Comment: strange, it seems only visual studio clang tools throws errors, when I use clang directly from the commandline it seems to work. Thanks!