# Visual Studio Code: C/C++ Intellisense not showing overloads

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Visual Studio Code does not show function overloads, as you can see on the screenshot. But as far as I know, Intellisense should show/suggest me all function overloads.

[image]

Just note that the code you see is the only file that is opened with vscode, there are no other includes.

What do I need to do so that function overloads will be displayed?

Comment: c_cpp_properties.json configures Intellisense. With that said I am not sure if there is a setting in there or not. This is not something I have investigated in my usage of VSCode. VSCode documentation: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)

Comment: The only thing I discovered is that when I change the insellisense engine from default to tag parser, then function overloads are being displayed. But when the tag parser engine is selected, syntax highlighting is not working properly anymore..

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense is actually correct, you can't overload functions in C. Well, you [technically can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026358), but not the way you are doing it.

Comment: The thing is: even if I change the language to C++, intellisense still won't show the overloadings.

Comment: @GorgonzolaBYTE Please change your file's extension to cpp and reupload the screenshot.